# How do I clear native PDF viewer as default?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, default-applications, pdf

I'm on Android Lollipop. Due to ghost touch, the native PDF viewer is selected default.

[image]
[image]

I also checked Reset Default Apps in the Settings menu, but there's only e-mail and messaging.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is (Google) Drive PDF Viewer, then:

1. Go to Settings
2. App and Storage (where you can see installed apps which are downloaded or pre-installed)
3. Select All Tab where you can see System Apps
4. Select Drive (triangle logo with three colors side green, yellow, blue)
5. Scroll down and click on Clear Defaults (if not available, directly check permission if available)

Note: Drive PDF Viewer has a red icon with a white Drive icon

[image] [image]

Comment: I don't remember what the name was, but had a red document icon, like Adobe Reader, but not. It's not in the list of applications.

goovle drive says no defaults set and the  button is grayed out, ghosted. I don't have enough screen for a screenshot with both name and   button.

I'm afraid I don't follow when you say "directly check permission if available."

Comment: Can u open any random pdf file with it and then send screenshots of opened file and opened app in recent list

Comment: Other is to check every apps launch by default, Normal red logo of PDF viewer is by uc browser, mega app Which i used but u have to check every app one by one its time consuming but will solve ur problem and let me Know which file manager u using they also have inbuilt PDF viewers

Comment: New screenshot added. Yeah, I really don't favr trolling every application, so I'll leave that for tomorrow nite if I have to. I've got ES File Explorer and the stock file manager. I added MiXplorer recently, but had the viewer beforehand.

Comment: Its logo and interface says its drive inbuilt pdf viewer if u don't have data on drive just clear data and then see.

Comment: Otherwise boot your phone to safe mode might then open any pdf file many options will appear so u can have idea which pdf viewer that was

Comment: I added screenshot in answer see it matches with your logo screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Google so no data (of mine) to lose, and that did it.

I did manage to find the core problem, tho. Opening an image file did the same problem: ghost touch selected Default as I tapped Gallery. Of course,  Gallery is right on the application list but again no default was set there or under Clear All, but I deleted the data and fixed it.

Something clicked that I thought to check ES File Explorer so I set Gallery as Default again and checked that app, ES. It didn't have a Default but I deleted that data and that also restored the "Open With..." menu.

So that's the problem: browsing with ES or maybe other file managers and selecting a default only applies to that manager (confirmed via browsing with the stock manager), and why no default shows in the application manager, and the solution is to delete data for either the defaulted application if known or the file manager.

Poor design on either ES or Google's part or both.

Thanks, @Kirandeep Maan, for the help and getting this solved!

Comment: U can give a try to solid file manager, Fx File manager or Astro file manager else if its same probably system bug for sure